# Array NullPointerException in particle system

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a custom particle system for a game I am beginning to work on. I have come upon a `NullPointerException` on my first test. I think I know *why* but I have no idea how I can fix it. Here is the related code:

```
ParticleSystem[] allParticles;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
    Random rand = new Random();
    allParticles[allParticles.length] = new ParticleSystem(
        rand.nextInt(10)+30,randomColor(),(int)me.getX(),(int)me.getY(), //this is 137
        rand.nextInt(10)+5,rand.nextInt(10)+5);
    return true;
}
```

Error:

```
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at com.laytproducts.pixelinvaders.GamePanel.onTouchEvent(GamePanel.java:37)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1746)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1117)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2092)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1730)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1794)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-04 20:53:27.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16805):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

That probably really isn't very good coding, so that's why I need some help. I think it has something to do with the fact that I am using `allParticles.length` as the position to add the system, is there a better way to do this? I already tried turning it into an `ArrayList` then doing `.add`; it also gave me a `NullPointerException` which also makes me think it has something to do with the other part of line 137.

SOLVED

Did this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(ParticleSystem p : allParticles){
        if(null == p){
            p = new ParticleSystem(rand.nextInt(10)+30,randomColor(),
                    (int)me.getX(),(int)me.getY(),15,15);
            Log.i("Pixel Invaders","ParticleSystem created: ");
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Java arrays have a fixed length. You can't add things to the end of them that way like you can in, say, JavaScript. Try posting your code that uses ArrayList.

Comment: Although, I would expect an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a `NullPointerException`. Probably `allParticles` is null, would be my guess.

Comment: Are you doing a new anywhere in your code for the array or arraylist? In the above.code your array is null, thus the error.

Comment: Fixed it myself by doing this: `@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
  Random rand = new Random();
  for(ParticleSystem p : allParticles){
   if(null == p){
    p = new ParticleSystem(rand.nextInt(10)+30,randomColor(),
      (int)me.getX(),(int)me.getY(),15,15);
    Log.i("Pixel Invaders","ParticleSystem created: ");
    break;
   }
  }
  return true;
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized the `allParticles` array. And even if you initialize it,

```
allParticles=new ParticleSystem[10];
```

then still you cannot access `allParticles[allParticles.length]` element, since the array index is from 0 to `allParticles.length-1`.

So your code has two problems.

Comment: Ya i know, But the problem is i have literally zero ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Actually you did not mention what you want to do in your code. I still cannot figure out... Please explain me what you are trying, then I will be help you.. thanks

Comment: I fixed it. Dont worry about it. I gave you best answer because you were the first to answer with something that helped atleast a little

Answer (score 0):

You are using `allParticles.length` but you haven't initialised the array to anything. Your array currently points to `null`.

I think what you are trying to achieve is to expand your array when you have something new to be inserted, but since Arrays need contiguous memory you cannot change its length at runtime. Try using `ArrayList` instead. It works as an expandable array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception from calling .length on allParticles.  You have to initialize the array first.  Even if that was working though, the call allParticles[allParticles.length] would be out of bounds because an array is indexed from 0 to length-1.

Comment: Yeah I know, but like I commented above I dunno how to go about fixing this because I need a way to add a particlesystem to the array then not override it (i remove the dead particlesystems from the array once dead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinkedList because linkedlist is a dynamic data structure whereas arrays is static.

To still use arrays either you have to know beforehand how many elements you will enter into the array to initialize it or you will have to initialize it to a very large number. But this is a bad approach in software design.